# BigQuery with different results

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a long query that involves multiple subqueries. But I receive null values in return if I run the query one way and no null values if I run the query another way that is effectively identical.

This example has been extremely simplified but the problem basically takes the following form. When I run a query like this one, no null sums are returned (which is the outcome I'm expecting):

```
WITH subquery1 AS (SELECT * FROM some_data WHERE value > 0), subquery2 AS (SELECT * FROM subquery1 WHERE name LIKE "%abc%") SELECT id, SUM(value) FROM subquery2 GROUP BY id
```

But when I run this query, I'm getting some nulls as sums back:

```
WITH subquery1 AS (SELECT * FROM some_data WHERE value > 0), subquery2 AS (SELECT * FROM subquery1 WHERE name LIKE "%abc%"), subquery3 AS (SELECT id, SUM(value) FROM subquery2 GROUP BY id) SELECT * FROM subquery3
```

The two queries are effectively the same. So I'm confused as to why I would get different results from the two.

Comment: i really doubt that "extremely simplified" example in your question actually represent your problem - above two examples must return same result! but obviously there is something else in your "long query that involves multiple subqueries" that causes the issue. so you should revisit examples in your question to better present your issue

Comment: @Mikhail Berlyant I made a slight change to the query examples above. Mainly trying to show that I have two queries where the outcome is exactly the same up until the final steps. If I run a simple SELECT * FROM subquery2, the outcome is the same in both queries. But when I add the final step to each query, I get different outcomes even though they are effectively the same. I wish I could share the actual queries but they involve internal data.

Comment: understood - but those simplified examples (in my mind - but I can be wrong) still hide the real issue. So question - when you run above two queries as is - do you still see the different result ?

Comment: Sorry yeah this one is really tough to fully explain/describe in this context. But I do get separate results from the full queries that I run. Do you have any advice for how we can resolve this problem such that we can work directly with the actual queries?

Comment: I think, without being able to reproduce the issue - we will not be able to help. So you need to think how to obfuscate your data (if this is the showstopper) and simplified your "long query" enough to present to us reproducible case